# Recent pseudo-documents per application in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, winapi

If you look at Classic Shell Start menu, you see that it has a section for recent applications. Every item in the section can contain popup menu, usually used for displaying recent documents, opened earlier in the application. For instance, the 'Word' item contains all .doc and .docx files recently opened in Word. I know a way to build such list: get all links from the 'Recent' folder and filter out matched documents, by .exe name.

But Classic Shell Start menu also shows popup menu for programs like RDC. For RDC client, namely, it shows a list of recent connections. It seems there is a concept of *pseudo-documents* in Windows, but I have never heard of it. How to get such list for a random .exe file?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell maintains the list of recent documents. [`SHAddToRecentDocs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows a program to add an item to the list.  The item can be:

- A path and filename
- A `PIDL` representing the shell object
- (Windows 7+) A [`SHARDAPPIDINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SHARDAPPIDINFOIDLIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure that identifies a shell item, and associated application.
- (Windows 7+) An [`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The key idea from the list and documentation is that the item can be a `PIDL`, which can represent a [fancy kind of 'file'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ID_Lists_PIDL). (What you called a `pseudo-document`. This is an oversimplification. Read the documentation.)

To obtain the recent files list, use [`SHGetFolderLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifying [`CSIDL_RECENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use the returned `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` to iterate the shell items.

If the item is not a file the list can be retrieved through the COM [`IApplicationDocumentLists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which requires an [Application User Model ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This excludes pinned items, for which there is no programmatic access for the same reason that [there is no access to the start menu pin list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx).

There are a lot of caveats to this, which is best explained by the documentation:

- [`SHAddToRecentDocs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762105(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Managing the File System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

(edited to add information about the jump list, and missing `IShellLink` from the list.)

Comment: Is it OK that Explorer doesn't show links to connections in the 'Recent' folder, because it filters them (as pure PIDL objects with no real file behind)? But enumerating will return the whole list, including them? And I just have to map links using the new API (`SHARDAPPIDINFO` or `SHARDAPPIDINFOIDLIS`) to map to the exe and the task is done?

Comment: 1) How explorer filters entries is entirely it's own decision, and subject to change, but in general `SHAddToRecentDocs` registers the specified application for specific file types. There's a lot of exceptions, so you're probably best off doing some experimentation and reading the docs to get the desired result. 2) The non-file items are added to the application's jump list, I'll add some info to the answer. 3) Generally, yes. The documentation has more information about the process.